# Binaries missing after reinstalling dnsmasq

Tags: apt

I'm running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and I accidentally removed /etc/init.d/dnsmasq and tried to get it back by reinstalling dnsmasq, which I got back after one or more of the following commands:

```
apt-get autoremove dnsmasq
apt-get install -f dnsmasq
apt-get install --reinstall dnsmasq
apt-get --purge remove dnsmasq
apt-get install --reinstall dnsmasq
```

however, now the binaries seem to be missing: apt keeps telling me the installation is only 73.7 kB and dnsmasq is not in /usr/sbin or anywhere else logical as far as I can find:

```
root@Raspberry-server:~# dpkg -L dnsmasq
/.
/etc
/etc/default
/etc/default/dnsmasq
/etc/dnsmasq.conf
/etc/dnsmasq.d
/etc/dnsmasq.d/README
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/insserv.conf.d
/etc/insserv.conf.d/dnsmasq
/etc/resolvconf
/etc/resolvconf/update.d
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/dnsmasq
/lib
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/resolvconf
/usr/lib/resolvconf/dpkg-event.d
/usr/lib/resolvconf/dpkg-event.d/dnsmasq
/usr/share
/usr/share/dnsmasq
/usr/share/dnsmasq/installed-marker
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/dnsmasq
```

I've already tried

```
apt install -f dnsmasq
apt install --reinstall dnsmasq
apt-get uninstall dnsmasq
apt-get remove dnsmasq
apt-get install dnsmasq
apt-get install -f
apt remove dnsmasq
apt clean
apt update
apt install --reinstall dnsmasq
apt install
apt upgrade
apt-get clean
apt-get install --reinstall -f dnsmasq
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dnsmasq
```

But nothing is working. How will I get it working again?

Answer (score 1):

after searching more and randomly inserting commands I've found that

```
apt install --reinstall -f dnsmasq-base
```

fixed my problem. It seems the problem was that the dnsmasq-base package wasn't properly reinstalled.